# RMI server ClassNotFoundException when client makes call

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I am trying to make a simple RMI execution engine to run on my local machine so that other java programs can easily run code on a second processor. (In the future this will be expanded to allow more processors).

The server starts up just fine, and the client appears to locate the registry ok, but when it tries to call the execution engine (and passes it a parameter) it causes a ClassNotFoundException.

I recognize that this is similar to many other questions on stack overflow, but as far as I can tell, all the other ones have to do with the client not being able to download the server's classes rather than the server not being able to download the client's classes.

Here is my code (copied almost exactly from [this sample code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html)):

## RMIServer eclipse project

ComputeEngine Interface:

```
package interfaces;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ComputeEngine_IF extends Remote {

    /**
    * @param task The task object specifying the computation to be performed
    * @return
    * @throws RemoteException
    */
    <T extends Serializable> T compute(TaskWithoutInput<T> task) throws RemoteException;
}
```

TaskWithoutInput interface:

```
package interfaces;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface TaskWithoutInput<T> extends Serializable {
    public T compute();
}
```

ComputeEngine Class:

```
package server;

import interfaces.ComputeEngine_IF;
import interfaces.TaskWithoutInput;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class ComputeEngine implements ComputeEngine_IF{

    public ComputeEngine() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends Serializable> T compute(TaskWithoutInput<T> task) throws RemoteException {
        return task.compute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }

        try {
            String name = "Compute";
            ComputeEngine_IF engine = new ComputeEngine();
            ComputeEngine_IF stub = (ComputeEngine_IF) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            registry.rebind(name, stub);

            System.out.println("Registry bound!");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ComputeEngine exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## RMIClient eclipse project

GetAnswerTask class

```
package client;

import interfaces.TaskWithoutInput;

public class GetAnswerTask implements TaskWithoutInput<Integer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Integer compute() {
        return Integer.valueOf(42);
    }
}
```

Client class

```
package client;

import interfaces.ComputeEngine_IF;
import interfaces.TaskWithoutInput;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class RmiClientExample {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if(System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }

        try {

            String name = "Compute";
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
            ComputeEngine_IF comp = (ComputeEngine_IF) registry.lookup(name);
            TaskWithoutInput<Integer> getAnswer = new GetAnswerTask();

            Integer answer = comp.compute(getAnswer);
            System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("RmiClientExample exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Both projects contain an identical security policy file (in RMIServer it is called server.policy and in RMIClient it is called client.policy)

```
grant  {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I will, of course, restrict the permissions more once I get this working.

## Building/Running

Since the code is pretty close to something I copied out of an example, my guess is that the code is right, or at least close, but that my mistake is in compiling/running the code. The example wasn't written for eclipse, so I don't have exact instructions.

The first thing I did was use eclipse's jar export wizard to jar the interface package into Interfaces.jar which I just placed in my RMIServer folder.

Then I run ComputeEngine with the following defines:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/c:/Users/nate/workspace/RMIServer/Interfaces.jar
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
-Djava.security.policy=c:/Users/nate/workspace/RMIServer/src/server.policy
```

The compute engine seems to run just find and outputs the print statement in the code.

I then run the client with the defines:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/c:/Users/nate/workspace/RMIClient/bin/
-Djava.security.policy=c:/Users/nate/workspace/RMIClient/src/client.policy
```

And I get the following error message:

```
RmiClientExample exception:
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.GetAnswerTask
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.compute(Unknown Source)
    at client.RmiClientExample.main(RmiClientExample.java:24)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.GetAnswerTask
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.GetAnswerTask
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler$Loader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClassForName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.unmarshalParametersUnchecked(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.unmarshalParameters(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`GetAnswerTask` implements Serializable, so it will be serialized to the server when you call `ComputeEngine_IF.compute()`. So `GetAnswerTask` needs to be available at the server, on its classpath, and it isn't.

Comment: My understanding based on this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html) was that by putting the class definitions in a publicly accessible place and setting the java.rmi.server.codebase variable to the url to that location, the server could then fetch the class definitions without needing to have the classes on its classpath. The whole idea of my RMI computation engine is to allow the server to execute code that isn't on its classpath so that any other java application could run their code on that generic processor.

Comment: PS. I tried removing the Serializable interface from TaskWithoutInput to see if that made a difference. Now I get "java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
 java.io.NotSerializableException: client.GetAnswerTask" which is interesting since in the tutorial I don't think that they ever used the Serializable interface. They tutorial talks about serialization, but I don't think it shows up at all in the example code.

Comment: So have you satisfised the conditions? Is the `java.rmi.server.codebase` property set at the client? Does it point to a location that is accessible under that name by the server? Have you tested that? Does your server's security policy permit access to the codebase server? Have you examined the server-side logs for the codebase provider to see what is actually happening? NB Removing `Serializable` from a class that needs it was a complete waste of time. I don't know why you bothered. The tutorial's [`Pi` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/client.html) implements `Serializable`.

Comment: java.rmi.server.codebase is set at the client. Since both processes are running on the same machine, it should be accessible to the server. I've verified the location by pasting the file url in IE. The server's security policy grants all permissions. I am not sure what you mean by examining the server-side logs. I didn't write any logging into my code (unless you count the print statements). Does the underlying RMI code or perhaps the RMI registry produce some logs? I'm not using Tomcat or anything, just java and RMI.

Comment: I asked for the server side logs because normally a codebase is an HTTP or FTP URL, both of which have logs. If you are using a FILE: URL there won't be any log to look at, but then if you're using a FILE: URL it can only really work if server and client are in the same host, in which case you don't need the codebase feature at all: you can just add the client's codebase directory to the server's classpath. If both processes are running in the same machine there's really no point in using the codebase feature at all.

Comment: Well, my idea was to make a generic compute process running on one machine that didn't have to know about all of the classes it is executing. The idea was that I could package it up and be able to include it with any product and that it would not have to be modified if you wanted to add support for a new task. I'd like to not need to change the classpath as more tasks are added (possibly from different codebases). That being said, at this point I've moved on from my original multi-processed approach and changed to a multi-threaded approach. So I really don't plan on pursuing this any more.

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling with oracle RMI tutorial, whose server doesn't download serializable class from given client's codebase (and stubbornly seeks class in its own codebase) - try to add

```
-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false
```

to **server's** arguments